# Can dynamic lock use face recognition to verify user presence before autolocking?

Tags: windows, webcam, lock

I think Windows Operating System is using face recognition over the webcam in the background to detect when am using it and if this returns false then it auto locks the device. I just left it for less than 5 minutes and discovered that Windows had already locked the device when I came back. There is the other Dynamic lock option for Bluetooth but that depends on the status of my phone's Bluetooth connection and it does not work when the Bluetooth on my phone is off. I programmed the settings to auto lock when there is a period of inactivity exceeding 30 minutes. I do not know if there is such a feature but also I hotspot my phone to my PC, and when I go away I kind of turn off the hotspot so maybe Windows detects that and uses that to lock the device or it checks for a face from the webcam at an interval and then locks the device, help me know what is making my PC behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic lock does not use your camera and doesn't need to.

Dynamic lock configures Windows to automatically lock when a
Bluetooth paired device signal falls below the maximum
Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI) value.

The idea is to make it more difficult to gain access to your Windows
if you step away from your PC and forget to lock it.

The answer is then that you specified that Windows should lock when your
phone is no longer near by. So when you walked away, with your phone
presumably in your pocket, Windows immediately locked itself.

Comment: But how did it know when bluetooth was off on my phone?

Comment: Dynamic lock tests the reception of your phone. When the reception is too poor, this means that you have went away, so it locks itself immediately.

Comment: What kind of technology does the reception testing rely on?

Comment: It's just Bluetooth - it's relying on the fact that Bluetooth works for only short distances. If you turn Bluetooth off in your phone or the computer, you then disable Dynamic lock.

Comment: But sometimes when I lay on the couch for hours, it does not lock and phone is off and charging but when I walk away with device it auto locks, what about wifi? Can be using the mobile hotspotting from my phone to make a distance judgement?

Comment: It's possible, even if Microsoft does not document this feature. But I'm just sure that it's not using the computer camera.

Comment: Okay am satisfied, Thank You

Comment: You're welcome.